# How to add an attribute name in HTML within Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, html

I have the following html that I"m trying to input into visualforce. The challenge is that I have attributes within the tags and I get the below error. I'm having trouble getting this in the correct format for apex, while also maintaining the functionality of my code?

```
Error: Attribute name "ts-default" associated with an element type "th" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table" ts-wrapper>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ts-criteria="Id">Id</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Name|lowercase" ts-default>Name</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Price|parseFloat">Price</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Quantity|parseInt">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by item.Id" ts-repeat>
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Price | currency}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try ts-default="" and ts-wrapper=""

Comment: I assume you are inputting your HTML content inside `<apex:outputText value="{!yourhtmlcontent}" escape="false" />`. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its Boolean HTML attribute which is not supported by Visualforce, so you need to use `ts-wrapper="true"`, So your table definition becomes
`<table class="table" ts-wrapper="true">`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a explanation on how to use custom HTML attributes in Visualforce. 
http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm